# ¿COMO AGREGO ESTA CONSULTA A UN PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

estoy intentando agregar esta consulta a un procedimiento, pero me generando error.

mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT( 
      CONCAT(
      'IF(MONTH(FECHA) = ''',
      IDMES,
      ''', TOTALVENTA, 0) AS ',
      NOMBREMES
    ))
FROM meses
where IDMES>=  MONTH('2023-09-01') AND IDMES<=  MONTH('2023-09-30') into @sql;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT alm.NOMALMACEN, ', @sql, '
                   FROM registrodiario AS r
                  INNER JOIN almacen AS alm
                  ON alm.CODALMACEN = r.ALMACENID
                  WHERE FECHA BETWEEN \'2023-09-01\' AND \'2023-09-31\' AND ALMACENID = \'1\'
                  ');

PREPARE consulta FROM @sql;
EXECUTE consulta;
```

El error es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Declara tu procedimiento y agrega la consulta dentro. [Revisa la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) y los ejemplos que hay allí. Si el código da error, agrega a la pregunta dicho mensaje de error, **como texto** no una captura de imagen y agrega también tu procedimiento como texto pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Te aconsejo que primero aísles tus consultas y las pruebes y cuando arrojen datos entonces las metas en el procedimiento. Por ejemplo, tu primera consulta es totalmente errónea, la forma correcta de escribirla sería: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(IF(MONTH(FECHA) = '', IDMES, ''),TOTALVENTA, 0)) AS  NOMBREMES  FROM meses WHERE IDMES>= MONTH('2023-09-01') AND IDMES<= MONTH('2023-09-30')` y con la segunda pasa algo peor, creas una variable y luego dentro de esa misma variable usas la variable para escribir la consulta. Escribe consultas limpias. Los SP están en el contexto de la base de datos!!!

Comment: la consulta está bien como la tengo amigo, me genera correctamente la información que requiero que es que me muestre el total de la venta por meses, el tema es cuando intento meter esa consulta en un procedimiento almacenado. de hecho, esta consulta la genere por un ejemplo e yusef en otra pregunta

Comment: Disculpa, no está bien la consulta. ¿No ves que el mensaje de error te dice que la consulta está mal?

Comment: A. Cedano, tranquilo tal vez no nos entendemos en lo que estamos intentando explicar cada uno.

Comment: Intente agregar `BEGIN` y `END` en la **Definición** de su procedimiento almacenado en phpMyAdmin (`BEGIN SET @sql = NULL; ... END`).

Comment: @wchiquito ¿en ese entorno `BEGIN` y `END` no se agregan solos? Observa que está trabajando en el generador de SP de phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Excelente compañero, agregando el BEGIN y el END me funciono correctamente. agradezco por sus aportes me ayudaron a resolver la necesidad que requería.

Comment: @A. Cedano si funciono como me lo sugirió -@wchiquito.

Comment: @A.Cedano justo pensaba lo mismo, pero haciendo pruebas en [phpMyAdmin](https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/), observé el comportamiento poco intuitivo.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. No obstante, me resulta extraño que tengas declaraciones propias del manejador entre comillas, por ejemplo: `'IF(MONTH(FECHA) = '''` ¿quizá porque la estás definiendo una variable? ¿No sería más natural definir las dos consultas seguidas y luego preparar y ejecutar?

Comment: las comillas simples es porque estoy concatenando dos tablas: meses y registro diario, esto para poder lograr que el titulo de la columna sea el nombre del mes y valor total por meses como los Datos de la misma columna.